# GitHub: Any way to check notifications after initial look?

Tags: github

Not sure if this question is appropriate, but I think it is (it is programming-related).  On GitHub, when someone responds to you you get a notification in the upper-right corner.

However, if you visit that page and then accidentally navigate away, you lose all your notifications.  Is there any way to manually query for "the last 5 things people said to me on GitHub", or anything like that?

Answer (score 1):

Github has a [Notifications API](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/notifications/). You can ask it for your read and unread notifications, or all notifications after a certain date.

Comment: Heh, thanks for the answer, but I was ideally looking for something web-based (I'd rather not have to write an entire application just to find a notification I missed).

Comment: @machineghost Oh. Hmm. You're talking about clicking on the little bell icon with the blue dot? When I do it takes me to https://github.com/notifications and I don't lose my unread notifications. You're saying you do?

Comment: Yes exactly.  The normal behavior for me (don't know if I changed a setting years ago or something, but ...) is for me to see the page when I first click the bell, but if I refresh or click a link and go back the refreshed page just says I have no notifications.  It just seems like any site (but GitHub especially) should provide some other way for me to get at least a superset of those notifications.